# Way to dealing with missing input values for each group

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, missing-data, binary-data

I am facing to a problem: I have tried to solve a binary classification problem and have a data set in which there are very many missing input values for its features. The training data looks like following;

```
0   X123474229,X51578397,X420128991,X174205309,X773579,X62718521,X773545,X51769735,X44092910,X41787959,X79805718,X344420902,X40087738,X374616379,X56982947,X62716332,Y2,Y1132,Y2267,Y2257,Y1080,Y1555,Y1222,Y1238,Y1702,Y2680,Y1705,Y1367,Y1353,Y2321,Y1486,Y1522,Y1940,Y977,Z4,Z15,Z25

0   X123474229,X302743259,X48786947,X89474323,X283926738,X62718521,X277692318,X315340932,X44092910,X417167762,X137608184,X216091985,X79805718,X147204623,X104964213,X236398246,X127436348,X367227997,X344420902,Y3269,Y3250,Y3232,Y3141,Y3143,Y2680,Y1705,Y2684,Y1725,Y2641,Y1690,Y2949,Y3021,Y2307,Y2321,Y1940,Z4,Z15

0   X123474229,X18006172,X564074277,X48786947,X442767451,X337793919,X277692318,X315340932,X104923833,X524837224,X44092910,X417167762,X551805107,X103413307,X216091985,X79805718,X147204623,X104964213,X127436348,X367227997,X344420902,X538427688,Y3269,Y1132,Y3250,Y3233,Y1080,Y3232,Y1555,Y1222,Y1238,Y3145,Y3143,Y1702,Y2680,Y1705,Y1725,Y2641,Y2170,Y1690,Y3021,Y2557,Y2307,Y1478,Y2321,Y1486,Y2024,Y1522,Y2817,Y3346,Y1940,Y977,Y1468,Z4,Z15,Z22

1   X773579,X344420902,X56982947,Y2,Y1478,Z4,Z15,Z27

1   X344420902,Y2,Z4,Z13,Z22
```

The first number in each line is an output (0/1) and the others in the same line are input data. As you can see, the number of data is inconsistent and the data looks to possibly be grouped/indexed by X, Y and Z for a batch of input.

I am thinking of using logistic regression for this. Could you please advise me on what kind of methods can be utilized to deal with this data set as input?

Thank you so much. 
Best regards.

Comment: Apologies for the typo: slave -> solve

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what your data actually is? Some background information would be nice, and maybe a better explanation of your data structure?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
The separation between the input data and output in the training set is by tab. And the separation between input data is by comma. Actually this is all what I know. I just need to figure out the relation between the input data which number is different for each input and output which is 0 or 1.

Comment: could LSTM be a solution for this?